# rails/VCR gem, same URI different method clash

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, vcr

My VCR configure block is:

```
VCR.configure do |c|
  c.cassette_library_dir = 'spec/fixtures/vcr_cassettes'
  c.hook_into :webmock

  c.around_http_request(lambda { |req| req.uri =~ /google.com/ }) do |request|
    VCR.use_cassette(request.uri, :decode_compressed_response => true, &request)
  end
end
```

My tests work fine for `post/get/put` methods but when I try to `DELETE`, there is a clash in VCR because it matches with a previous PUT request. This is because the URI for that request is the same as the one needed for the DELETE request.

How do I change my `use_cassette` method so that it uses a combination of URI + method? (or any other suggestion also welcome!)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, this might help others, so leaving it here:

`VCR.use_cassette([request.uri,request.method].join.to_s, :match_requests_on => [:method, :uri], :decode_compressed_response => true, &request)`